# Export env variable inside double quotes in bash

Tags: bash

So this command works fine:

```
bash -c 'export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo $JUPYTER_HOME'
> /home/jupyterlab
```

but the double quote variation does not set the variable:

```
bash -c "export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo $JUPYTER_HOME"
>
```

I am forced to use double quotes in my problem as this is inside a program I do not control that creates the double-quoted string command.  I've tried certain variations like `${JUPYTER_HOME}` with no effect.

Comment: `echo $JUPYTER_HOME` is being replaced with the current value before the child copy of bash is started.

Comment: Mind -- _why_ do you think you need to use double quotes here? Shell quoting is character-by-character -- even if you need double quotes for part of your string for a reason that isn't shown here, that doesn't mean you need to use them for the whole thing. That is to say, `'foo'"bar"` is the same as `foobar` is the same as `"foobar"` is the same as `'foobar'`; they're all just different ways to represent the exact same string. So one can write `echo "hello "'$'"foo"` to write `hello $foo` to stdout with everything _except_ the `$` being in double quotes, and the `$` alone being single-quoted.

Comment: "a program I do not control that expects a double-quoted string" -- incredibly unlikely. Programs can't tell how you quoted their arguments.

Comment: That is to say, `foo 'bar'` and `foo "bar"` look **exactly the same** to the program `foo`. It has no possible way of knowing which one you used.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right. the program creates a double-quoted string. I supply parts.

Comment: Then you can provide parts that change the quoting type. If it concatenates with something like the Python code ```"prefix \"" + yourstring + "\" suffix"```, then you can make yourstring be (the literal string) `"' whatever '"`, so it ends the double-quoted string and starts a single-quoted string, and then changes back to a double-quoted one at the end.

Comment: ...if you can provide a reproducer that combines the pieces you give it the same way your real program does, I'm happy to construct an example of an argument that'll work with it.

Comment: (aside: changing shell quoting types in ways that surprise the caller is a key skill of folks trying to build shell injection exploits, which is part of _why_ concatenating strings together to build a command to execute with a `system()` call or similar is such a bad smell re: likely security bugs).

Comment: Escaping the $ as Alvaro pointed out works fine. Thanks

Comment: `"'$'"` would probably work just as well as `\$` does. They're both doing the same thing -- telling the shell that the `$` is literal -- but the former is doing it by changing the quoting type from double quotes to single quotes temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the **$**:

`bash -c "export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo \$JUPYTER_HOME"`

---

#### Explanation

This is because when using double quotes the interpreter is trying to replace `$JUPYTER_HOME` with its value. For example, check what it happens when you do:

`JUPYTER_HOME="what?";bash -c "export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo $JUPYTER_HOME"`

It will echo `what?` because it is the same as executing:

`bash -c "export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo what?"`

In your case, where $JUPYTER_HOME had no value it was actually executing:

`bash -c "export JUPYTER_HOME=/home/jupyterlab && echo "`

Comment: Or just use single quotes, as in the first command in the question which "works just fine".